# How to redirect using .htaccess file that redirects from clear domain to www.?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, short

How to redirect:

from mydomain.pl to www.mydomain.pl/start

and

from www.mydomain.pl to www.mydomain.pl/start using .htaccess file?

This should not interfere with any other page. Eg. when somebody types mydomain.pl/contact this should only add www. before the domain.

Comment: Why `.htaccess`? Easier and more efficient to do it in the main server config as a separate VHost with a `Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/`

Comment: Mosl likely, but mu server does not allow that ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mydomain.pl/start [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about mydomain.pl/start? This should only add www. before the domain, but its not.

Comment: perfect! Can I make this more universal and change RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.pl$ [NC] to RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^%{HTTP_HOST}$ [NC] ?

Comment: `RewriteCond` can be skipped actually if have just these 2 domains.

Comment: Thank you again, I appreciate your help.
Now works as expected :)